# Creating default object from empty value using dropzone and laravel ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, dropzone.js

i have in an annonces table a multiple images, i want to update multiple images, but it gives me error: Creating default object from empty value,I just want to send the data to controller but it gives me error:Creating default object from empty value.

**AnnoncesController.php**

```
public function filesUpdate(Request $request)
    {
      dd($request->all());
    }
```

**details.blade.php**

```
     <form method="post" action="{{url('annonces/filesUpdate')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="dropzone">
                                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
                                {{ csrf_field() }}                            
                             </form> 
<script type="text/javascript">
            Dropzone.options.dropzone = 
            {
            maxFilesize: 12,
            renameFile: function(file) {
                var images = [];
                var id     = $('.id').val();
                $(file).each(function(i){
                  images[i] = file.name;
                });
                $.ajax({
                 url:"{{ url('annonces/filesUpdate') }}" ,
                 type:'POST',
                 data:{
                    images  : images,
                    "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
                },
                 success: function(data, status, xhr){
                  console.log(data, status, xhr);
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, msg) {
                  return console.error(xhr, status, msg)
                }})
               //return  images;
            }, 
            acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            timeout: 50000,
            success: function(file, response) 
            {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(file, response)
            {
               return false;
            }
            };
  </script>
```

Comment: Which line and file does the error refer to?

Comment: @El_Vanja THX for u answer error exist in function controller filesUpdate

Comment: Is that `dd` really all you have inside that function?

Comment: @El_Vanja yes, I think the error is that  request is empty

Comment: Have you tried just dumping the entire request object (`dd($request)`)? It seems as though it's null.

Comment: @El_Vanja i tried removing the controller function it gives me same error, then the error in details.blade.php `$.ajax({  url:"{{ url('annonces/filesUpdate') }}" ,`